# How to remove leading and trailing zeros in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 so the FORMAT function is not available.  Is there a succinct way of removing leading and trailing zeros from a decimal.

Other answers I have found on stack overflow don't cover all scenarios.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @d decimal(9,6) = 12.345
SELECT removezeros(@d)
```

I realise that the result will be a string.

It should work for all of the following cases:

```
0.123000    -> 0.123
1.23        -> 1.23
012.003450  -> 12.00345
1.00        -> 1
```

Comment: What are the options you found/tried?

Comment: Is the leading `0` on the result from `0.123000` definitely required?

Comment: You could try casting to float, look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8d4e/1), there might be issues with precision though, not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table #t(id decimal(9,6))
insert into #t values(0.123000),(012.3879000),(1.23),(1.00)

select cast(id as float) from #t
```

## <kbd>[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15697)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible, but seems to work with floats and numerics.  The key is converting to numeric first if your value is a float.

```
declare @val numeric(18,5) = 012.003450;
SELECT ISNULL(REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(CAST(@val as nvarchar(max)),'0',' ')),' ','0'),'.',' ')),' ','.'),'');
```

1. Cast floats as numerics
2. Replace zeros with spaces
3. Right trim spaces
4. Revert spaces back to zeros.
5. Do the same for the decimal place

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to do this, try this below.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT TOP(5)CurrencyRateID, EndOfDayRate
            ,FORMAT(EndOfDayRate, 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Number Format'
            ,FORMAT(EndOfDayRate, 'G', 'en-us') AS 'General Format'
            ,FORMAT(EndOfDayRate, 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Currency Format'
FROM Sales.CurrencyRate
ORDER BY CurrencyRateID;
```

Here is the result set.

```
CurrencyRateID EndOfDayRate  Numeric Format  General Format  Currency Format
-------------- ------------  --------------  --------------  ---------------
1              1.0002        1.00            1.0002          $1.00
2              1.55          1.55            1.5500          $1.55
3              1.9419        1.94            1.9419          $1.94
4              1.4683        1.47            1.4683          $1.47
5              8.2784        8.28            8.2784          $8.28

(5 row(s) affected)
```

It can be found on the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: Read the first line of the question again: "I'm using SQL Server 2008 so the FORMAT function is not available."